# Is there a need to renew the Self Signed Cert for Single Sign On if Salesforce is not the Identity Provider?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, certificates

Based on this help [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_about.htm&type=0) and this [community post](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000BghEQAS), can we allow the Self Signed Cert within Salesforce to expire if we do not use Salesforce for an Identity Provider? Is there any harm in doing this? We have a lot of sandboxes with this configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have decided to let the CERTs expire in our sandboxes, but renew them in Production. Though our SSO does not currently validate the CERT (only uses the metadata), we wanted to be safe and just renew them.